# Detecting data changed in Android

Tags: java, android, ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am developing an app for android and I have a java/android class that acts as a data controller which contains methods that update/delete/add data. I was wondering if there was a way for me to determine if the data has been updated/deleted/removed from within another class. I am looking for something like nsNotificationcenter in IOS, where you do something like

```
  let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

  notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userDefaultsDidChange), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `LiveData` from [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use RxJava. There is a lot of questions like that on stack:

[RxJava - observe data that might always change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504037/rxjava-observe-data-that-might-always-change)

[Android Rxjava subscribe to a variable change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738760/android-rxjava-subscribe-to-a-variable-change/43680015)